# Variation of geometrical quantities under infinitesimal deformation of surfaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, perturbation-theory

This question is about 2-d surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

It's easy to find information on how the metric  $g_{\mu\nu}$  changes when $x_{\mu}\rightarrow x_{\mu}+\varepsilon\xi(x)$.

So, what about the variation of the second fundamental form, the Gauss and the mean curvature? how they change?

I found some works on the topic, but, alas, they are expressed very abstractly, so for now they are beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to look at the appendix of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1137/120885553), where these issues are addressed. The paper also provides references to the more 'standard' results concerning variations of surfaces.